# Invoking a JSP Page from a Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Can anyone tell me if there exists any method other than RequestDispatcher, to invoke a jsp page from my servlet? Because i have tried a lot without success.

My servlet works normally and recovred all the data from jsp. All that I need is to be redirected to another page when the user enters the username and password correctly.

my code :

first my servlet " login"

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

}


  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse      response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        String user = request.getParameter("username");
        String pass = request.getParameter("password");         
      System.out.println(" le user est "+user+ " le mot de passe est " + pass);

          String query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '"+user+"' and password='"+pass+"'";

      dbconn = new DBAccess();
      Connection conn = dbconn.connect();

         stmt = conn.createStatement();
         ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(query);

            if(res.next()){
              ServletContext sc = this.getServletContext();
              RequestDispatcher rd =sc.getRequestDispatcher( "inscreption.jsp");
              rd.forward(request, response);   
                 System.out.println(" il existe");

            }else { 
           ServletContext sc = this.getServletContext();
            RequestDispatcher rd = sc.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
             //   RequestDispatcher rd =request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
                rd.forward(request, response);   
                System.out.println("not found");


      }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


    finally{
        System.out.close();
    }





    }}
    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
      */
   /* @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>
```

my jsp that i would to be redirected for

```
<html>
<head>
    <!--local jquery-->
    <script  src="jQuerys/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script  src="jQuerys/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel ="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jqueryMobile-1.3.1.css"/>
    <!--/local jquery-->
      </head>

      <body>
<div data-role="page" id="inscription">
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
    <center>CERIST</center>
</div>
                  <form id="insc" method="post" action="login">

  <div data-role="content">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="identifiant">Identifiant </label>
        <input type="text" id="identifiant"/>
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="password1">Mot de passe </label>
        <input type="password" id="password1"/>
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="password2">Confirmation</label>
        <input type="password" id="password2"/>
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
            <legend>Vous &ecirc;tes :</legend>
                <input type="radio" name="profil" id="radio-choice-1" value="Candidat" />
                <label for="radio-choice-1">Utilisateur</label>

                <input type="radio" name="profil" id="radio-choice-2" value="Entreprise"  />
                <label for="radio-choice-2">Administrateur</label>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <a href="#" data-role="button" onclick="">S'inscrire</a>

        </form>

  </div>
 </div>
      </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where are your jsp files stored in regards to your deployment? Also, read about Little Bobby Tables in [xkcd 327 - Exploits of a Mom](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: Why would you want to "invoke a JSP from a servlet" ?

Comment: to fill out another form

Comment: @AbdelbakiElfodil, share the url-pattern for the given servlet and the jsp path with respect to web folder. Also share the error you get while redirecting to jsp

Comment: @Arvind JSP PATH : C:\Users\W.W\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PFE\web\inscreption.jsp

Comment: servlet path : C:\Users\W.W\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PFE\src\java\com\servlets\login.java

and i dont have any error when i execute i just stay on my first jsp page

Comment: *"if there exists any method other than RequestDispatcher"* => no, there is no other method. This sounds like an example [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you need to pass data to JSP from the servlet, use [request attributes](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29). These can be accessed from the JSP (e.g. via [expression language](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html)).

Comment: you can use `response.sendRedirect(String yourPageUrl)`

Comment: @AfsunKhammadli i use it but still don t work

Answer (score -1):

### index.jsp :

```
<form action="Myservlet" method="post"><br>
            User name`<`input type="text" name="username"`>`<br>
            Password `<`input type="password" name="password"><br>
            `<`input type="submit" value="Submit" `>`

</form>
```

### Myservlet.java:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.print("Oppos!!!");

}

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String user = request.getParameter("username");
    String pass = request.getParameter("password");
    RequestDispatcher rd;
    if (user.equals("username") && pass.equals("password")) {
        rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/inscreption.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    } else {
        rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/wrong.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);

    }
}
```

You can create more than two pages where you want to dispatch your request so here I created more than two jsp page names: `right.jsp` and `wrong.jsp`. If the username and password is correct then it frowards to `right.jsp` page if it's wrong, it frowards the request to `wrong.jsp` page.

Comment: still doesn t work ..you d ont think that i can have a problem with url path ?

Comment: please check this line rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/inscreption.jsp");
and also check web.xml file where <servlet-mapping>